# Javascript: print character that skips to next cell in Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, google-sheets, character-encoding

In a Javascript file, I want to print a sequence of numbers, each separated by a character such that when I paste this output into an Excel table or Google Sheet, each number is in a consecutive cell. Something like this:

`console.log('1\t2\t3')`

except that if I paste the output of that into Excel, it prints all three numbers into the same cell, separated by a tab. What's the character that I should be using instead of a tab?

Comment: Try something like `SendKeys ("1{TAB}2{TAB}3");`
`

Comment: Not sure if or how this would work through JS, but if you got an Excel 365 file, maybe you can input a spilling array of numbers instead?